# getting Polymer Paper spinner to appear while body is unresolved

Tags: jquery, html, polymer

I want to get the polymer paper spinner to appear while the body tag has the unresolved attribute set to it.I get a few seconds of blank screen before the page fully loads.

I honestly have no idea how to get started.

https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/paper-spinner.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the loader via jQuery to the blank screen body and remove it when you have your response.

```
$('body').append("<div class='loader'><img src='/loader.gif'></div>");
```

where the loader class will contain the loader.

Comment: I'm a bit confused (Sorry I'm still an amateur)..so do I add this line of code to the first line after my body tag?

Comment: You may want to refer to jQuery tutorials to understand how this works. Try http://www.w3schools.com for learn more on this.

Comment: You can start with this http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp and then move slowly move to jQuery.

Comment: okay thanks.. will have a read through it